# Want to generate a new date time, which is not in the list of date time intervals using c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Peak time intervals like

```
7:00:00 to 7:59:59
8:00:00 to 8:59:59
9:00:00 to 9:59:59
10:00:00 to 10:59:59
16:00:00 to 16:59:59
17:00:00 to 17:59:59
18:00:00 to 18:59:59
19:00:00 to 19:59:59
```

Now I want to get the list of off peak time intervals or off peak time atleast which does not fall in the above mentioned time intervals.

I am trying to do this with linq query but unable to do so, my entire code is in c#. Can anyone of you help me to get this done?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: please show your code to better illustrate your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't mentioned how you are representing the Date Range, am assuming that you have a class in place, which has a Begin and End property as follows.

```
public class DateRange
{
    public DateTime Begin{get;set;}
    public DateTime End{get;set;}
}
```

And then your PeakTime Intervals are represented as

```
var today = DateTime.Now;
var excludeList = new List<DateRange>()
{
    new DateRange
    {
        Begin = new DateTime(today.Year,today.Month,today.Day,3,0,0),
        End = new DateTime(today.Year,today.Month,today.Day,3,59,59),
    },

    new DateRange
    {
        Begin = new DateTime(today.Year,today.Month,today.Day,7,0,0),
        End = new DateTime(today.Year,today.Month,today.Day,7,59,59),
    },
};
```

You can now generate the Time Range for the day using

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0,24).Select(x=> 
                        new DateRange{ 
                            Begin = new DateTime(today.Year,today.Month,today.Day,x,0,0),
                            End = new DateTime(today.Year,today.Month,today.Day,x,59,59)
                            }).Where(x=> !excludeList.Select(c=>c.Begin).ToList().Contains(x.Begin)
                                        && !excludeList.Select(c=>c.End).ToList().Contains(x.End));
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort your intervals, and rewrite any overlapping intervals to no longer overlap.  Your sample data set suggests this is already done.
I wouldn't recommend using Linq for this, since you have to measure between all the items.  I think it's more readable with a simple for loop:

Given a simple class `Interval(TimeSpan Start, TimeSpan End)`, and the list of intervals you provided as `List<Interval> intervals`:

```
TimeSpan gapBetweenIntervals = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1); // since all your sample intervals have 1 second gaps
List<Interval> complement = new List<Interval>(intervals.Count + 1);
complement.Add(new Interval(new TimeSpan(), intervals[0].Start - gapBetweenIntervals));
for (int i = 0; i < intervals.Count - 1; ++i)
{
    complement.Add(new Interval(intervals[i].End + gapBetweenIntervals, intervals[i + 1].Start - gapBetweenIntervals));
}

complement.Add(new Interval(intervals[intervals.Count - 1].End + gapBetweenIntervals, new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0) - gapBetweenIntervals));
complement.RemoveAll(i => i.Start > i.End);
```

This gives the list:

```
00:00:00 to 06:59:59 
12:00:00 to 15:59:59 
20:00:00 to 23:59:59
```

Just for fun, I did rewrite this with Linq, though I'm not sure I'd recommend using this:

```
var lowerBounds = new[] { new TimeSpan() }.Concat(intervals.Select(i => i.End + gapBetweenIntervals));
var upperBounds = intervals.Select(i => i.Start - gapBetweenIntervals).Concat(new[] { new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0) - gapBetweenIntervals });
lowerBounds.Zip(upperBounds, (l, u) => new Interval(l, u)).Where(i => i.Start < i.End);
```